# Calling AWS ELB public DNS from AWS EC2 client. How much do I get charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, dns, aws-billing

I have an EC2 based client that calls this public DNS of this AWS ELB in the same region and I am trying to save money on EC2-Internet public traffic and want to keep all the data within AWS cloud.
I want to know since I am calling from one AWS service to another. Does AWS services internally know how to keep this traffic within AWS ecosystem and save me internet data transfer charges?
Is setting up a VPC between the EC2 client -> AWS ELB is the only way to save on public internet traffic?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, packets from an AWS resource to another AWS resource will not route over the internet.

Comment: Any docs I can read about it ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/how-it-works.html#what-is-aws-global-network

Comment: I see that section says `Traffic that is in an Availability Zone, or between Availability Zones in all Regions, routes over the AWS private global network`. But how come EC2->EC2 in the same region is a billable event but EC2->ELB in the same region is not ? Something feels wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is an [internal load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html)

> The nodes of an internal load balancer have only private IP addresses. The DNS name of an internal load balancer is publicly resolvable to the private IP addresses of the nodes. Therefore, internal load balancers can only route requests from clients with access to the VPC for the load balancer.

You dont have to create vpc for that, default vpc will also work just make sure your ec2 and internal LB are in the same **private vpc** and subnet as prerequisite.

How to do it, read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-internal-load-balancer.html)

Coming to question `Does AWS services internally know how to keep this traffic within AWS ecosystem and save me internet data transfer charges`

If its within the same region using internet gateway it is free, if it uses nat gateway within same region it will cost, but if request falls cross region it is not free, Ref: [Data transfer cost](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/overview-of-data-transfer-costs-for-common-architectures/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I do have to create a VPC between the client and ELB. Can you also answer my 1st question ?

Comment: As I said default vpc will also work and I have update my answer do take a look. Also read how to setup internal load balancer it will help.

Comment: Are you sure about : "If its within the same region using internet gateway it is free" ? Why would I use VPC then if I can use internet gateway for free ? I think only the public `Service Endpoint` of AWS service within same region is free. No ?

Comment: Did you read my any of the links I provided? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/overview-of-data-transfer-costs-for-common-architectures/?

Comment: Yes, I had already read them before posting this question. They are useful but don't answer my question directly.